# Get 5 random images from custom post type galleries

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a custom post type called "project" and within this post type is 10 posts (projects), each post contains a few images/gallery.

I have a sidebar and I want the sidebar to generate 3 random images pulled from the galleries of the custom post type "project".

I have this code but it doesn't seem to work correctly.

```
<ul class="gallery">
        <?php
            $loop = new WP_Query(array(
                'post_type' => 'project', 
                'posts_per_page' => 0, 
                'orderby'=>'rand',
            ));
        ?>
        <?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>

            <?php $images = get_field('gallery'); ?>
            <?php shuffle ($images); ?>
            <?php if ($images): ?>
                <?php foreach (array_slice($images, 0, 3) as $image ): ?>

                <li style="background-image: url(<?php echo $image['url']; ?>);">

                </li>

                <?php endforeach; ?>
            <?php endif; ?>

        <?php endwhile; ?> 
    </ul>
```

Comment: How does it misbehave exactly? Does it generate any output? Wrong output? Wrong images? What does the resulting HTML look like? How many images exist in the DB for the test page?

Comment: how can you get posts with posts_per_page=0?

Comment: It pull out ALL the images from ALL the posts, I want to limit it to 5 random images.

Comment: zairwolf - posts_per_page=0 means unlimited.